# Smartface 4.3 ios horizontal orientation

Tags: smartface.io

I have created and new empty project at Smartface 4.3  with defaults and export to xcode with "Portrait" "Landscape Left" and "Landscape Right" options selected. I have also selected xcode orientations as vertical and horizontal. At vertical orientation everything is ok but if horizontal orientation selected screen divided  and don't fetch the screen as below picture half of the screen is black. I am using xcode 6.3 with OS X Yosemite 10.10.3. Is there any more setting on xcode or smartface to solve problem?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use horizontal layouts by selecting from Project Details -> App Settings section.

We suggest to use horizontal or vertical orientation for application, supporting all the orientation requires MVC modeling hovewer it is not completely supported.